# How to escape serverside characters in JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asp.net

#### What my plugin is and what my issue is

I am developing a JS (jQuery) plugin for a virtual keyboard, which should have all the letters that a simple keyboard have.

#### My local website

I am using ASP.NET Razor WebSite to test this plugin on, so that means any character that I have to care about should relate to or belong to ASP.NET such as `@`. But `@` won't be read in a site that would be running on PHP and PHP might try to play around with `$` button, since my plugin is JS (pure jQuery) so what can I do to escape this?  I am not that much perfect in PHP, so I won't know about other PHP characters. That are on Keyboard which might need to be replaced too to make sure PHP don't misunderstand the character and start a serverside block.

#### Provide a JS suggestion

Any jQuery (JS) suggestion would be preferred to minimize this issue, cross-"server-side"-language! So my plugin should work and show all the keyboard button virtually on site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JavaScript is running in the browser. The server side code is irrelevant to it.

You might use JavaScript to send some input to the server, but then you just deal with it as you would any other user input. Don't evaluate it as code, use prepared statements before injecting it into SQL, convert it to HTML before inserting it into HTML, etc.

Comment: No no brother, I think you got my point wrong. I know the JavaScript works in client side. But the issue is in ASP.NET when I write `id="@"` it is recognised as a start for the server-side code, which is not good! Similarly in other languages there might be a breakpoint where a character might be a server-side start. I have been through the ASP.NET one, so I thought I should give JS hold of the code to avoid all the errors like this! Get my point?

Comment: And you're correct, I can use jQuery to send Ajax request then read it as ASP.NET save it then get the response and write it. But that's different approach..

Comment: Writing `id="@"` won't cause anything to be recognised as an ASP.NET anything … unless maybe you are embedding your JS in an ASP.NET template, but don't do that, use a static .js file.

Comment: Hmmmm..your second idea is perfect :) Thanks..

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you mean but I think you can just use javascript escape

```
var text = escape(yourtext);
```

Comment: I want the server not to read the special character of whatso ever language it is running! And please note that I have the code in HTML.